# ruby: fixing double utf-8 encoded strings with invalid characters?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding

I have invalid characters inside some text in my database (eg: `â€˜`instead of `'`) because of copy-pasted content.
Exporting this text to google merchant returned the following error: `Encoding problem(Double UTF-8 Encoding)`.

Is there any way to restore characters which have been converted from latin-1 to utf-8 twice, or filter them out without replacing any valid eurpoean characters in other areas (eg: `â` in valid french text)
Have been researching this for a while now, havent found anything which would help with this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

I discuss that particular issue [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixing_double_encoding_), with 4 solutions.  Caveat:  The code there has not been thoroughly tested.